# Can XALAN verify XSLT during transformations?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

Can XALAN perform some checks during transformation for the possibly dangerous XSLT?

XALAN transformations are commonly used for XML to HTML transformations. So, it is possible that someone can write dangerous code which will internally initiate remote code execution or start accessing user data.

Is there a way we can configure XALAN to prevent remote code execution?

Comment: See whether https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/properties.html gives you some insight and options to improve security.

Comment: There is also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING as a more general safeguard.